# Как добавить в меню Drawer Layout текст?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Здравствуйте. Как добавить в меню Drawer Layout текст? Подробности на рисунке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы используете просто menu.xml? Попробуйте использовать Menu Adapter. Тогда Вы сможете подставить вместо текста xml.

Comment: Да использую  menu.xml.  Спасибо за совет, попробую с адаптером...